# Python Class method: Subtracting two vectors

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a custom vector class:

```
class VectorND:

    def __init__(self, *args, max=0):
        self.args = args
        max = len(args)
        self.max = max

    def __add__(self, x):
        if len(x.args) != len(self.args):
            raise Exception("Vectors are not same length")
        sum_coords = []
        for i in range(self.max):
            h = self.args[i] + x.args[i]
            sum_coords.append(h)
        new_coords = tuple(sum_coords)
        return VectorND(new_coords)
        
    def __subtract__(self, x):
        if len(x.args) != len(self.args):
            raise Exception("Vectors are not same length")
        sum_coords = []
        for i in range(self.max):
            h = self.args[i] - x.args[i]
            sum_coords.append(h)
        new_coords = tuple(sum_coords)
        return VectorND(new_coords)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n >= self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        entry = self.args[self.n]
        self.n += 1
        return entry

    def __str__(self):
        return "Vector: {[0]}".format(self.args)
```

Here, I am attempting to represent vector subtraction, but I get the following error when running this bit of code:

```
vec1= VectorND(1,2,3)
vec2 = VectorND(3,4,5)
vec3 = vec1 + vec2
print(vec3)

vec4 = vec2 - vec1
print(vec4)

>>>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'VectorND' and 'VectorND'
```

`vec3` produces the correct result of `(4,6,8)`; however, `vec4` throws the TypeError. I am not sure why this is happening as the only difference between the add and subtract method is, well, subtracting the entries of the tuple. What is the nuance between these two different methods that is causing this error?

Comment: In addition to Sai's answer: see the [documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function `__add__()` is an overloaded form of predefined function in python, which is mapped to "+" operator.
however `__subtract__()` is not mapped to any operator.

Instead try using `__sub__()` as it is mapped to "-" operator.